# i want to print a string array in reverse in c but its giving me an error

Tags: c

I don't know why I am getting an error, I want to print the array in reverse, for exmaple if I entered `hello`, it would print `olleh`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define S 25
void reverse(char a[S]){
for(int i=S-1;i>=0;i--){
        printf("the inverse is : %c\n",a[S]);
    }
}

int main()
{
char mystring[S];
printf("input your string:\n");
for(int i=0;i<S;i++){
scanf("%c",&mystring[S]);}
reverse(mystring[S]);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would really make it easier to help if you included the error message you get.

Comment: You are scanning and printing a[S] and mystring[S] instead of a[i] and mystring[i]. Also,when calling the function, the syntax is reverse(mystring) not reverse(mystring[S]). Also, have you considered using %s instead of %c?

Comment: Indenting your code propely also definitely helps to spot bugs

Comment: `for(int i=S-1;i>=0;i--){` is wrong too. You start inconditionally at the end of the array, even if the string it contains is shorter. Actually almost everything is wrong in your code.

Comment: how is everything wrong in my code @Jabberwocky

Comment: the whole point that when i run my code, it only asks me to enter my string and then it stucks

Comment: Didn't you get compiler warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are many things wrong in this code. For example:

1. Inside the for loop you must write &mystring[i] for inputting the string character by character.Also for inputting a string you should simply use %s as it automatically provides you with the escape sequence character at the end which can be further used to compute the inputted string's length and perform various operations with it.
2. while passing an array you should only pass its name as arguments.
3. defining `S=25` the array you made has indexes 0-24 by writing `mystring[S]` you are trying to access an out of bounds array element which will give a buffer overflow error.
4. `"hello"` will only take the first 5 character places inside the array so to print its reverse you should simply find its end point using '\0' and then print the reverse string from there.
5. to find the inputted string's length you can use the above method or simply include string .h header file and use the in-built library function `strlen` with proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 25                          // using menaingful name MAXLENGTH instead of a

void reverse(char string[MAXLENGTH]) {        // using menaingful name string instead of a
  int length = strlen(string);                // using correct string length
  for (int i = (length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("the inverse is : %c\n", string[i]);
  }
}

int main()
{
  char mystring[MAXLENGTH];
  printf("input your string:\n");
  scanf("%s", mystring);                      // using correct input of string      
  reverse(mystring);                          // using correct argument (mystring instead of mystring[S]
  return 0;
}
```

It does not exactly what you want, but it's a start.